# Theme the View/Edit Tabs

Tags: theming

I would like to be able to theme the view/edit tabs.

That is, I'd like to add a class to the `<li>`.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create tabs use this module: http://drupal.org/project/tabs

else you can modify the tab wrapper in your **page.tpl.php** and then costumize your tabs with the api functions, to see more read:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/theme_menu_local_task